# Which name is shown next to improved edit suggestions?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Is it the one that has improved the suggestion, or the original creator of the suggestion?

Comment: The one who improved it but the original editor still gets the +2 rep.

Comment: And how is it listed in the statistics? Does it count as an approved edit for the original editor?

Comment: Yes, improve edit first accepts the edit like normal, then the reviewer can make further edits.

Comment: Ok, do you want to post this as an answer? Then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a suggested edit is improved, it creates two entries in the edit history:

- one for the suggested edit
- one for the improved edit

This makes it clear to see which editor did what.

Here's an example:

[image: Suggested edit approval with additional edit from reviewer]

As you can see above, both edits have the same time stamp - "14 secs ago", which tells you that they were submitted at the same time.

Additionally, you can see that the edit was "approved" in edit #3, so the person who submitted it still gets credit for it.

If, on the other hand, the edit is rejected and edited, only one edit would appear, that of the reviewer.